# Laravel 8: Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type integer

Tags: laravel, api

I have project in Laravel 7 and it worked. But, for some reasons, I want to refactor to Laravel 8. Others are okay, but this one route has a problem.

Here's my route code in L7 (worked) and L8 (error):
Route api.php:

```
L7:
Route::get('/coa/find', [Setting\CoaController::Class, 'findCoa']);

L8:
Route::get('coa/find', 'Setting\CoaController@findCoa');
```

And this is my controller (same code):

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Setting;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Coa;

class CoaController extends Controller
{
    public function findCoa(Request $request)
    {
        $isi = $request -> isi; 
        $findCoa = Coa::where('coaid', 'ilike', "%" . $isi . "%")
        ->orWhere('deskripsi', 'ilike', "%" . $isi . "%")
        ->paginate(20);
        // $findCoa = DB::table('coa')
        // ->where('coaid', 'ilike', "%" . $isi . "%")
        // ->orWhere('deskripsi', 'ilike', "%" . $isi . "%")
        // ->paginate(20);

        return response()->json($findCoa);
    }
 }
```

Either I use DB or model in App\Coa, it always resulting this error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: &quot;find&quot; (SQL: select * from &quot;coa&quot; where &quot;id&quot; = find limit 1) in file /Users/yosep/Dropbox/projects/Laravel8/kie-l8/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 692
```

I didn't understand why the query become:
`select * from &quot;coa&quot; where &quot;id&quot; = find limit 1`? No matter I change the controller, it always resulting that error. But other method (index, show($id), destroy) are okay. Just this one still messed up.

Comment: Already tried that, but still no luck, error message still same. Query in error not same as controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how it works, but I change the api.php, from this:

```
Route::get('/coa/{id}', [Setting\CoaController::Class, 'show']);
Route::get('coa/cari', [Setting\CoaController::Class, 'findCoa']);
```

to this:

```
Route::get('coa/cari', [Setting\CoaController::Class, 'findCoa']);
Route::get('/coa/{id}', [Setting\CoaController::Class, 'show']);
```

And both of it works!

Can anyone explain, why show api/method couldn't wrote first and resulted that error?

Comment: With your first route setup, when you call `/coa/cari`, your route `'/coa/{id}'` is hit first (basically saying "a URL starting with `/coa/`, then anything). You could also restrict the parameter `{id}` to only use integers using [Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints), which should make your routes work like in your first setup

Answer (score 0):

The first thing in Laravel 8 route controller binding has been changed to make your route work

> Route::get('coa/find', 'Setting\CoaController@findCoa');

You should update your "RouteServiceProvider.php" do find "protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';" or just add this line This will work!